# Share variables in Playground

Tags: swift, variables, global-variables, swift-playground, xcplayground

I’ve got a public class with variables declared in a sources file. I’m trying to set these variable in page 1 (of the playground book) to use in page 2.
At the moment I can see the class but it doesn’t allow me to access the variables even if I declare them as public.

**Data.swift**

```
 public class GlobalVars {
       public var progress = Float()
       public var didComplete = Bool()

}
```

**Contents.swift**

```
GlobalVar().progress = 1
```

I'd also tried this

**Data.swift**

```
 public class GlobalVars {
       public var progress:Float?
       public var didComplete;Bool?

    public init() progress:Float? = nil, didComplete:Bool? = nil {
    self.progress = progress
    self.didComplete = didComplete
    }

}
```

They're optionals so I can set each individually but when I set one everything else is then set to nil. If I try get a value after I set it, I still get nil.

Comment: How are you trying to access the variables, could you post some code ?

Comment: added some code @IonescuVlad

Comment: that it is not how it works, you should use the singleton pattern if you want to access shared variables

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton pattern in order to be able to access shared variables. Here is a code that will work in your case. Add the GlobalClass class to source

```
     import Foundation
   // GlobalVars.swift has to be in source files     
        public class GlobalVars {
           public var progress:Float = 0.0
           public var didComplete:Bool = true
           public static let sharedInstance = GlobalVars()
            private init() {}
        }
```

And in your page you can use it after like this.

```
import UIKit

GlobalVars.sharedInstance.progress = 1
GlobalVars.sharedInstance.didComplete = false
print(GlobalVars.sharedInstance.progress)
print(GlobalVars.sharedInstance.didComplete)
```

I've just tested this and it works

Comment: That's what I usually use in Xcode but I tried and doesn't work between playground pages

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same result in playgrounds though? @Moritz

Comment: well I've edited to make it more clear my answers and it works.

Comment: It does work on one page. I want to use that value in the next page as well. When I go to the next page the value is 0 @IonescuVlad

Comment: @Junaid, each page has it's own run , so what that does, it cleans the data after the run is finished. I think what you actually want is to persist data in one page and read it in another ? Playground supports CoreData according to apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/AvailableSDKs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017343-CH5-SW2

Comment: I have a feeling CoreData won’t work cause UserDefaults didn’t either. Let me try switch to a normal playground from a playground book@IonescuVlad

Comment: What is your end scope, use case ?  maybe playground is not the best option.

Comment: @IonescuVlad It has to be a playground cause it’s for a wwdc submission. I did some looking up and found that there’s some called ‘PlaygroundShareUserDataDirectory’. I can’t find any examples on it but it says that it’s for saving data between playgrounds https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundshareddatadirectory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167360/discussion-between-junaid-and-ionescu-vlad).

Comment: Idk playgrounds is messed up. I tried UserDefauts again and it works @IonescuVlad